# Does "be done -ing" mean "not doing something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[This](https://youtu.be/Fi5Nk48zCJk) video is a debate about gun control after mass shootings in Florida. ([3:05](https://youtu.be/Fi5Nk48zCJk?t=3m05s))

> Ted: And I think people, republican members of congressman and republican senators, who think this is the right thing to do, ought to vow that they're not going to support their leader. They **should be done voting** for Paul Ryan unless he's willing to stand on the side of the victims, the families, the kids, the students from Stoneman Douglas.
>
> ...
>
> Alison: How about that, congressman Curbelo? Do you still support their leaders?

I understood this sentence, "They *should be done voting* for Paul Ryan" in this context, as "they(Republican Congressmen) *should not vote* for Paul Ryan (in the next election or something), unless he's going to support gun control." 
I'm not used to the usage of this phrase(done -ing), so I'm not sure if it's right or not.

Does *done -ing* mean *not doing something in the future*?

Comment: 1. I think he says **ought to vow that**. 2. Are you done cleaning the floor? Not yet. What? You should already be done cleaning the floor! What's taking so long? I think **should be done doing something** simply means that you should already be finished doing whatever it is that you're doing.

Comment: In the context of your example, it means that people who vote for Paul Ryan should stop doing that/should not do that anymore.

Comment: Thanks I corrected it. Then "should be done -ing" indicates future tense? Like, they should not vote for him in the future?

Comment: Exactly. They've been voting for him all these years and now they should stop doing that. Meaning, from now on, no more voting for that guy. That's what he's suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an idiom "To be done —ing" which means "to have finished —ing". In modern use it tends to be casual and is more common in American than British English. It is fairly emphatic; it means to be completely finished.

> Karen, you're done playing with the dough. You left the table and said you were finished, so go find something else to play with.

In your context, it means that *Republican representatives who support gun control should stop voting for Paul Ryan*. I understand "for Paul Ryan" to mean "For the policies that Paul Ryan supports"